# How to center vertically a floating div inside an inline-block?

Tags: css, html, jsfiddle

I'm trying to center vertically a div inside an inline-block,
I used this inline-block to get automatically size of child in order to center my div.

The problem is my children div are floating... in order to constrain it to the left/right position.

Here is how the HTML look like :

```
<span class="block_container">
    <div class="block_text"> <!-- float:right -->
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block_image"> <!-- float:left -->
        <img src="test.png"></img>
    </div>
</span>
```

However, I can't figure out this problem : http://jsfiddle.net/kl94/nH2sd/

Edit:

Here is what I want :
[image]

Here is what I tried :
http://jsfiddle.net/kl94/nH2sd/

Comment: Is this browser specific? The fiddle looks fine to me on FF

Comment: Hmmm no, the target is for mobile device but it should works everywhere. I don't try on IE and I don't have to support it ...

Comment: Share a screenshot of how you want and what is it right now that is not fine. As I agree with Kevin that it looks fine. - @kl94

Comment: @kl94 You may need to describe your expected outcome a littler better, an image would be very helpful.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for confusions

Comment: I'm a retard, I put a wrong fiddle url... sorry guys

Comment: post the updated one. - @kl94

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the actual vertical alignment working the way you want it to work as per your attached screenshot, you have to change a few things.

**1. Adding a *`display:table-row;`*** to the parent block.

**2. Removing all floats and replacing it with *`display:table-cell;`***

This will enforce the exact characteristic of `vertical-alignment` to co-exist and work the way you want it to work as per the attached screenshot.

Here is the [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nH2sd/2/)

**The HTML:**

```
<span class="block_container">
        <div class="block_image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Gnu_meditate_levitate.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="block_text">
        <div class="bgColor">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <p>I should be align vertically but the problem is i don't know my left neightbor height...</p>
            <div>
    </div>
</span>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.block_text {
    /*background: red;*/
    /*float: right;*/
    width: 60%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.block_image {
    background: yellow;
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 40%;
    display:table-cell;
}

.block_image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height:auto;
}

.block_container {
    background:teal;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    display:table-row;
}
.bgColor{background:red;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this possible that the table-row is align horizontally to middle ?

Comment: Yes it is. 
http://jsfiddle.net/nH2sd/4/ (with a new parent wrapper Div)
http://jsfiddle.net/nH2sd/5/ (with table-row as the parent Div) - @kl94

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/LlEvs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.block_text {
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 300px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background: yellow;
}

.block_container {
    background:teal;
    display: inline-block;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="block_container">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Gnu_meditate_levitate.png"><div class="block_text">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <p>I should be align vertically but the problem is i don't know my left neightbor height...</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for my curiosity, when you zoom in, the red text box does not wrap with the parent and jumps to the next line. Is it a limitation?

Comment: Yes indeed, it does seem to be. Yours is a much better solution. That was my preferred option, but I tried inline-block first. I was going to post a table version, but you beat me to it. I didn't use table-row, but apart from that the solutions were the same. I'll upvote you. :-)

Comment: Thnx @ralph.m Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this:

`margin-top: 13%;` at your `.block_text` selector in CSS.

Comment: But what about when we don`t know how much is the height of left div ?